# Currency connections

Tags: visual, steganography, graph-theory

Two Forex traders are trying to communicate about their trades.
They send each other images with a hidden meaning like this one:

[image]

Can you work out which currencies they are trading?

**Hint:**

> There's more than one way to describe a graph

Comment: Can we have a hint?

Comment: rot13(Vf gur rqtr sebz 5 gb 3 zrnag gb or gurer? Bgurejvfr, gur nqwnprapl zngevk ebhtuyl ybbxf yvxr gur flzoby sbe ehcrr.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You learn something new every day! The currencies they are exchanging are:

> The British pound and the American dollar

Reasoning:

> Represent the given graph with an adjacency matrix, so the entry in row  and column  is a 1 if and only if there is an edge from node  to node , and zero otherwise. Doing this gives the matrix:
>
>   $$\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\end{matrix}$$
>
>  Looking at the rows as binary numbers, and converting them to letters with A1Z26 yields the word CABLE. Per Wikipedia (so it must be true), "Cable (or the cable) is a foreign exchange term used for the GBP/USD currency pair rate (British pound priced in US dollars)."

Comment: This is clever!

Comment: Well done! I was worried it was too tricky.

Comment: Nice work! I thought there will be a character encoded in the binary matrix image and got stuck.